# How to test an automatic transmission attached to non running engine?

Tags: transmission, durango

I purchased a 2004 Dodge Durango SLT 4x4 with the 4.7, when I bought it I was told it needed a few things before it will run mainly cooling components but after speaking to the owner before the guy I bought it from Ive learned it may have transmission issues.

Im looking for a way to help me discern if this is indeed the case or if it was fixed before I bought it,  because it needs a starter, cooling fan, radiator, and misc other things I cannot start it to see if it works  but I need to know so I can decide how to proceed and prioritize my parts list for money and time if it needs a transmission that becomes top of the list etc.  Its an automatic and in the truck I have the two back wheels off the ground held up by jackstands on the rear axle, the transmission fluid has a black tinge and smells burnt so much so that I noticed it in the cab at the time I was looking at it but thought it had been a wiring issue  is it possible to test or am I screwed?

Comment: Once the fluid is burned the transmission life is at a minimum. Burnt fluid is indication the trans clutches are toast and the trans needs a rebuild.